# ¿Es posible encriptar el javascript de una web creada con Html5 ?¿ se puede?

Tags: javascript, html5, aplicación-web, encriptación

Quisiera saber si se puede encriptar el javascript de una web creada con Html5 y de ser cierto esto, ¿es seguro hacerlo ? ¿ no trae problemas al momento de ejecutarse en el navegador ?  es que quiero encriptar mi javascript

Comment: Se puede utilizar la <b>ofuscación</b> con <i>Uglify</i>. [Aquí](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Proteger-y-hacer-mas-agil-tu-codigo-JavaScript-Minimizacion-y-ofuscacion.aspx) puedes consultar más al respecto.

Comment: Se puede utilizar la <b>ofuscación</b> con <i>Uglify</i>. [Aquí](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Proteger-y-hacer-mas-agil-tu-codigo-JavaScript-Minimizacion-y-ofuscacion.aspx) puedes consultar más al respecto.

Comment: que mi código no sea legible para la vista de otros, quiero decir que no lo puedan leer fácilmente, mas que todo para evitar posibles ataques de inyección de datos en el js.

Comment: pero la ofuscación se vuelve legible al presionar Prettify, por ejemplo, si un usuario quiere ver mi js en su navegador lo puede hacer, lo unico que tiene que hacer es entrar en el inspector de elementos ir al js y simplemente darle al boton Prettify y se mostrara de nuevo mi codigo js.. ¿o Me equivoco ?

Comment: Si, si es posible. Busca "ofuscar javascript" en Google. Intenta alguna de las soluciones que encuentres y si tienes problemas, pregunta aquí todas las veces que necesites, incluye cuando puedes un __[mcve]__, solo recuerda que no están permitidas las preguntas que piden opiniones, consejos, ideas o sugerencias.  Sigue esta guía _[ask]_.

Comment: @toledano Esta pregunta no pide opiniones, consejos ideas o sugerencias. Pregunta si es posible encriptar javascript de una web creada con Html5. La respuesta es sí o no y es objetiva. Pregunta si es seguro, la respuesta es sí o no y es objetiva aunque puede que cambie en el futuro si aparecen vulnerabilidades. Y pregunta si trae problemas al ejecutarse en el navegador; y esto es algo que también es medible objetivamente. +1 y mantener abierta.